# Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "makePoll" is not found

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I've tried to do this simple poll function using python for my discord bot:

```
@command(name="makePoll")
@has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def createPoll(self, ctx, question, *options):
    if len(options) > 10:
        await ctx.send("You can only supply a maximum of 10 options.")

    else:
        embed = Embed(title="Poll",
                     description=question,
                     colour=ctx.author.colour,
                     timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    fields = [("Options", "\n".join([f"{numbers[idx]} {options}" for idx, option in enumerate(options)]), False),
              ("Instructions", "React to case a vote!", False)]

    for name, value, inline in fields:
        embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And the problem is that it throws me an error when I try to call the function.
The error:Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "makePoll" is not found.

edit: tried to name client.command makepoll but know it gives me this error:Ignoring exception in command makePoll:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\first try on python\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "F:/first try on python/for loop/bot1.py", line 40, in createPoll
colour=ctx.author.colour,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\first try on python\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "F:\first try on python\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "F:\first try on python\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: Can you try to do `@client.command(name="makePoll")` instead of `@command(name="makePoll")`?

Comment: import discord, import time, import random, from discord import Embed, from date time, from discord.ext import comands, tasks, from itertools import cycle from discord.ext.comand import has_permissions, command

Comment: @Nurqm used your method but now it throws out a completely different error

Comment: Try `commands.command(name='makepool')`.

Comment: error:Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "makePoll" is not found. And how i called it:<makePoll "this is a test" one two three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your edit, it says ‘str’ object does not have ‘author’ attribute.

And the str object is referring the `ctx` in your function. You don’t have to add the variable `self` because I don’t think that this command is in a class.

Discord.py sees this, and thinks “self is the **context**, ctx is a string argument(for the command)…”

The solution is to remove “self”.

So the code is:

```py
@client.command(name="makePoll")
@has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def createPoll(ctx, question, *options):
    if len(options) > 10:
        await ctx.send("You can only supply a maximum of 10 options.")

    else:
        embed = Embed(title="Poll",
                     description=question,
                     colour=ctx.author.colour,
                     timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    fields = [("Options", "\n".join([f"{numbers[idx]} {options}" for idx, option in enumerate(options)]), False),
              ("Instructions", "React to case a vote!", False)]

    for name, value, inline in fields:
        embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

`self` is mostly used in classes btw

I also suggest you to set the name of the command same as the function name